# internal server error ajax asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

hi i'm writing an ajax code that get data from the database server with web service but avery time i try to get data sho me Error : internal server error

am doing something wrong here..

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
                url: "CreerEquipe.aspx/GetFrmtionShema",
                data: "{'id':'" + parseInt(id) + "','formation':'4-4-2'}",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                success: function (res) {
                    alert(res.d);

                    $('.formation').html(res.d);
                    //alert(schema);

                    //$("#TotalDEF").html("(" + Count + "/5)");
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert('Error : ' + error);
                }
            });
```

other side in webmethode :

```
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod]
        public static string GetFrmtionShema(int id,string formation)
        {
            string data = "";
            ConGeters Config = new ConGeters();
            Config.Cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_Formation where id_formation = @id", Config.con);

            Config.Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            //Config.Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            Config.Open();
            Config.Dr = Config.Cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (Config.Dr.Read())
            {
                data = Config.Dr[4].ToString();
            }
            Config.Close();
            Config.Dr.Close();
            return data;
        }
```

Any advises please ? i'm blocked for 2 days

Comment: What is the specific error you are getting?  Check the output tab inside Visual Studio for a stack trace.

Comment: you pass a formation but never use it on the server side...
data: "{'id':'" + parseInt(id) + "','formation':'4-4-2'}",
public static string GetFrmtionShema(int id,string formation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use string concatenation to pass parameters, my friend. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
                url: "CreerEquipe.aspx/GetFrmtionShema",
                data: JSON.stringify({ id: parseInt(id), formation: '4-4-2' }),,
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                success: function (res) {
                    alert(res.d);

                    $('.formation').html(res.d);
                    //alert(schema);

                    //$("#TotalDEF").html("(" + Count + "/5)");
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert('Error : ' + error);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

i checked your ajax request to server is fine. I think you should check your code without using method it's is working or not. internal sever error comes when code having bugs. check your code

```
`ConGeters Config = new ConGeters();
            Config.Cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_Formation where id_formation = @id", Config.con);

            Config.Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            //Config.Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            Config.Open();
            Config.Dr = Config.Cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (Config.Dr.Read())
            {
                data = Config.Dr[4].ToString();
            }
            Config.Close();
            Config.Dr.Close();`
```